# Tiered calculations with two variables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I create a table that collects sales data from various methods. And part of the information in that table is :

```
salespersonid   netSales
90  12428660.00
90  300000.00
90  250379.00
90  170061.50
650 163250.00
```

I have to calculate the commission based on following table:

```
ServiceFeeRebateTypeId  SalesPersonId   ServiceFeeRate  SamFundRate SalesLimitStart SalesLimitEnd   IncludeInTier   RebateName
2   115 4.00    1.00    0.00    NULL    0   Sales Rep
2   116 4.00    1.00    0.00    NULL    0   Sales Rep
2   116 4.00    1.00    0.00    NULL    0   Sales Rep
3   NULL    6.00    0.50    0.00    NULL    0   Owner
3   NULL    5.00    0.50    0.00    NULL    0   Owner
1   NULL    5.00    0.50    0.00    NULL    0   Customer
1   NULL    5.00    0.50    0.00    NULL    0   Customer
1   NULL    3.00    0.25    0.00    NULL    0   Customer
4   NULL    8.00    1.00    0.00    50000.00    1   Tier1
5   NULL    7.00    0.75    50000.01    100000.00   1   Tier2
6   NULL    6.00    0.50    100000.01   NULL    1   Tier3
3   NULL    4.00    5.00    0.00    NULL    0   Owner
3   NULL    6.00    0.50    0.00    NULL    0   Owner
4   NULL    7.00    0.75    50000.00    100000.00   1   Tier1
5   NULL    6.00    0.25    100001.00   416666.00   1   Tier2
4   NULL    12.00   1.00    0.00    50000.00    1   Tier1
1   NULL    2.00    3.00    0.00    NULL    0   Customer
5   NULL    5.00    5.00    50000.00    100000.00   0   Tier2
4   NULL    0.25    0.50    0.00    50000.00    0   Tier1
5   NULL    0.50    1.00    50000.01    100000.00   0   Tier2
2   NULL    6.00    0.50    0.00    NULL    1   Sales Rep
2   875 5.00    0.25    0.00    NULL    0   Sales Rep
```

Following example is one that need to account for:
Bob receives $175,000 from customer payments in the month of January, and all of these are included in tier sales.

Bob’s Tier 1 is 0 – 50,000 – Service Fee Rate = 8.00% and Sam Fund Rate = 1.00% So his “Service Fees” total 9.00%

Bob’s Tier 2 is 50,000.01 – 100,000  - Service Fee Rate = 7.00% and Sam Fund Rate = .50%, So his “Service Fees” total 7.50%

Bob’s Tier 3 is 100,000 – 9,999,999 – Service Fee Rate =  6.00% and Sam Fund Rate = .25%, So his “Service Fees” Total is 6.25%

```
Tier Rebate Sales   Range   Sales Amount    Percent Rebate Amount   Total
Tier 1  0 to 50,000 50,000  0   0   0
Tier 2  50,000.01 to 100,000    50,000  1.50% (which is calculated by Subtracting the Tier 1 Service Fees 9% - Tier 2 Service 7.5%) $750 - Which is the Sales Amount * the percent  $750 
Tier 3  100,000.01 to 9,999,999 75,000  2.75%  (which is calculated by Subtracting the Tier 1 Service Fees 9% - Tier 3 Service 6.25%)   $2062.50 -  Which is the Sales Amount * the percent 2812.5


            Grand Total 2812.5
```

There are several other conditions that I have finished matching using CASE statements. 
This calculation will also require calculation but I am struggling it to set up.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to add `Service Fee Rate + Sam Fund Rate`???  It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Please consult the following article: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). Following the guidelines in that article will make it a lot easier for people around here to help you. GL!